# where does ^{pageBody pc} come from?

Tags: haskell, yesod

In default-layout-wrapper.hamlet file, there is ^{pageBody pc} which allows me to embed body content. I can find the *pc* part in Foundation.hs file. but where is pageBody constructed (in what file)?
Same question for this variable #{pageTitle pc}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoogle on stackage.org is a great resource for these kinds of questions:

http://www.stackage.org/lts/hoogle?q=pageBody

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Yes, it will help the user tremendously in his future, but you should at least add `pageBody`'s current location.

Answer (score 0):

pageBody is a function that is called on the "variable" called pc.  Like Michael said, pageBody is part of the standard Yesod library.  It will be evaluated when your page template is processed by the whamlet engine (this is what the ^{...} does).  If you actually create a scaffolded site with Yesod, take some time to read through the auto-generated handling functions - you will see there how templates are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified types:

```
data PageContent url = PageContent
    { pageTitle :: Html
    , pageHead :: HtmlUrl url
    , pageBody :: HtmlUrl url
    }
widgetToPageContent :: Widget -> Handler (PageContent url)
```

...
And code example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}
import           Yesod

data App = App
mkYesod "App" [parseRoute|
/ HomeR GET
|]

myLayout :: Widget -> Handler Html
myLayout widget = do
    pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
        widget
        toWidget [lucius| body { font-family: arial } |]
    withUrlRenderer
        [hamlet|
            $doctype 5
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>#{pageTitle pc}
                    <meta charset=utf-8>
                    ^{pageHead pc}
                <body>
                    <article>
                        ^{pageBody pc}
        |]

instance Yesod App where
    defaultLayout = myLayout

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout
    [whamlet|
        <p>Some text!
    |]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 App
```

and at scafolding Foundations.hs:

```
defaultLayout widget = do
    master <- getYesod
    mmsg <- getMessage

    -- We break up the default layout into two components:
    -- default-layout is the contents of the body tag, and
    -- default-layout-wrapper is the entire page. Since the final
    -- value passed to hamletToRepHtml cannot be a widget, this allows
    -- you to use normal widget features in default-layout.

    pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
        addStylesheet $ StaticR css_bootstrap_css
        $(widgetFile "default-layout")
    withUrlRenderer $(hamletFile "templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
```